# Scrapy Pipeline not starting

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm having problems with Scrapy pipelines.
EnricherPipeline is never starting. I put a debugger in the fist line of process_item and it never gets control.
JsonPipeline does start, but the first argument it receives is of type `generator object process_item` and not the MatchItem instance it should receive (when I disable the EnricherPipeline, JsonPipeline works as expected.

```
class MatchSpider(CrawlSpider):

    def parse(self, response):
        browser = Browser(browser='Chrome')
        browser.get(response.url)
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(), "{l}") and @title="{c}"]'.format(l=self.league, c=self.country)).click()
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//select[@id="seasons"]/option[text()="{s}"]'.format(s=self.season.replace('-', '/'))).click()
        browser.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(), "Fixture")]').click()
        page_matches = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class, "result-1 rc")]')
        matches.extend([m.get_attribute('href') for m in page_matches]
        for m in matches[:1]:
            yield Request(m, callback=self.process_match, dont_filter=True)

    def process_match(self, response):
        match_item = MatchItem()
        match_item['url'] = response.url
        match_item['project'] = self.settings.get('BOT_NAME')
        match_item['spider'] = self.name
        match_item['server'] = socket.gethostname()
        match_item['date'] = datetime.datetime.now()
        return match_item

class EnricherPipeline:
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.match = defaultdict(dict)
        self.match['date'] = item['match']['startTime']
        self.match['referee'] = item['match']['refereeName']
        self.match['stadium'] = item['match']['venueName']
        self.match['exp_mins'] = item['match']['expandedMinutes']
        yield self.match


class JsonPipeline:

    def process_item(self, item, scraper):
        output_dir = 'data/matches/{league}/{season}'.format(league=scraper.league, season=scraper.season)
        if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
            os.makedirs(output_dir)
        file_name = "-".join([str(datetime.strptime(item['date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S').date()),
                              item['home']['name'], item['away']['name']]) + '.json'
        item_path = os.sep.join((output_dir, file_name))
        with open(item_path, 'w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps(item))



ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'scrapers.whoscored.whoscored.pipelines.EnricherPipeline': 300,
    'scrapers.whoscored.whoscored.pipelines.JsonPipeline': 800,
}
```

Comment: You have another pipeline, 'scrapers.whoscored.whoscored.pipelines.EnricherPipeline': 300. What does this pipeline return?

Comment: Strangely, Scrapy never enters that pipeline. I put a debugger on the first line of process_item and it never enteres. It is supposed to return a dict.

Comment: _Strangely, Scrapy never enters that pipeline._ Is the code you posted from a single file (e.g. `pipelines.py`) or different files? `ITEM_PIPELINES` is expected to be set in the `settings.py` file.

Comment: Yes, ITEM_PIPELINES it's in the settings.py file. JsonPipeline is in pipelines.py and MatchSpider is a scraper.

Comment: Could you provide a run log? When you run scrapy spider, before it starts it outputs some info logs. Check whether your pipeline is in the lines below `[scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:`.

Comment: Yes, there are both there:
2016-09-22 10:09:47 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['scrapers.whoscored.whoscored.pipelines.EnricherPipeline',
 'scrapers.whoscored.whoscored.pipelines.JsonPipeline']

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem was that EnricherPipeline was yielding and not returning a result. After that it worked as expected, although I still don't understand why a debugger is not working in that first pipeline.

Comment: If your spider never yields any results then pipeline's `process_item()` is never called, thus debugger's break point never reached.

Comment: My spider does yield results.

Comment: There are some ways to tell whether the first pipeline is called. (a). through scrapy logs, to check whether your pipeline is enabled. (b) In your process_item() function, do some print or logging, then check whether this function is called.

Answer (score 0):

I write scrapy code like @FranGoitia, using return item in dict type, and it can go to pipeline well.

Answer (score -1):

**The true reason is:**

Can't not yield any type not `base on dict`, the scrapy engine will not call pipeline.

Odds, I spend three days to found this...

Comment: No, i try to yield with dict and it can go into pipeline!

Comment: @RockyChen It should be worked. Maybe there has other issue in your project.